# problem that i encountered when trying to convert a user-defined class to buildin class"int" via overloading =

Tags: c++, class, constructor, operator-overloading

**as follows**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int val;

    A(int n)
    {
        val = n;
    }

    A()
    {
        val = 123;
    }

    int &GetObj()
    {
        return val;
    }

    int operator=(const A &a)
    {
        return a.val;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int m, n;
    A a;
    cout << a.val << endl;
    while (cin >> m >> n)
    {
        a.GetObj() = m;
        cout << a.val << endl;
        a.GetObj() = A(n);
        cout << a.val << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

everytime ERROR appeared instantly when i tried to compile the program .remaining the main fuction unchanged,how can i modify the program to make sure itll pass? maybe i should focus on a constructor or type of GetObj?

Comment: `a.GetObj()` returns `int`, `A(n);` is a constructor.

Comment: *"everytime ERROR appeared"* - and that specific error should be included *verbatim* in your question, along with what, if anything, you think it means, and what, if anything, you've done to try to correct it. I *suspect* you need a *conversion operator*, but without  more clarity of the goal of this code that is a pure guess.

Comment: Change `a.GetObj() = A(n);` to either `a.GetObj() = n;` or to `a = A(n);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by overloading the "cast operator"…

```cpp
struct A {
  int val;
  A(int i) : val{ i } {}
  operator int() const { return val; }
  A& operator=(int i) { val = i; return *this; }
};

int main() {
  A a = 10;  // A::A(int)
  int i = a; // A::operator int() const
  a = 11;    // A::operator =(int)
  return a - i; // implicit conversion of A to int
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/PGGM7zder)

Comment: Thank you all guys! it's my fault that haven't clarify the purpose and request of this problem clearly.(i admit that my previous clarity is quite confusing)the limit is,you can only change part of the program ,even part of the "class" statement(oh it's really awful and stupid),concretely,the part of "class"statement below the constructor A(int n),,and the expected output is ,firstly,123,then,the value of **m** and **n** that you input before

Comment: and inspired by all of you,i got a solution like this:

Comment: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
 int val;

 A(int

 n)
 {
  val=n;
 }
 A()
 {
  val=123;
 }
 A & GetObj()
 {
  return *this;
 }
};
int main()
{
 int m,n;
 A a;
 cout << a.val << endl;
 while(cin >> m >> n) {
  a.GetObj() = m;
  cout << a.val << endl;
  a.GetObj() = A(n);
  cout << a.val<< endl;
 }
 return 0;
}`

Comment: it's so ugly,but lets forget it now,i've got three new confusion:

Comment: 1.what does the pointer `*this` mean?return itself right?                                 2.could i conclude that when two types of data appear at the right side of = ,it means we need operator overloading or constructor to solve it.but when ,which,and how?                  3.let me think for a while ,forgot

Comment: `this` when inside an object is a pointer to the object you're currently in, so in order to return a `reference` it has to dereferenced using the `operator *`.  
So, yes, `this` is a pointer to "this" instance of the class.